# converting a string to a date in C#

Tags: c#

I was wondering how I would convert a string of four to six digits to a date in C#?

`111110 would be 11 11 10`

`111 10 would be 11 1 10`

`1 1 10 would be 1 1 10`

The pattern being `mmddyy` `mmd yy` `m d yy`
and the spaces are either `' '` or `'\0'` (the input I am given is not very clean)

This what I have so far and it works for all above cases, its just not very pretty:
Is there a more efficient solution to the above cases?

```
//Converts the given input string into a valid Date
private DateTime convertToDateFromString(string dateString)
{
  int length = dateString.Length;
  int month = 1;
  int day = 1;
  int year = 1;
  bool gotMonth = false;
  bool gotDay = false;
  bool gotYear = false;
  char c = ' ';
  char peek = ' ';
  string buffer = "";
  DateTime bufferDate;
  int count = 0;

  try
  {
    //loop character by character through the string
    for (int i = 0; i < dateString.Length; i++)
    {
      c = dateString[i];
      if ((i + 1) < dateString.Length)
        peek = dateString[i + 1];
      else
        peek = '\0';

      if (c != ' ' && c != '\0')
      {
        buffer += c;
        count++;
        //Check if the month is done
        if ((peek == ' ' || peek == '\0' || count == 2) && gotMonth == false)
        {
          count = 0;
          gotMonth = true;
          month = int.Parse(buffer);
          buffer = null;
        }
        //Check if the day is done
        else if ((peek == ' ' || peek == '\0' || count == 2) && gotDay == false && gotMonth == true)
        {
          count = 0;
          gotDay = true;
          day = int.Parse(buffer);
          buffer = null;
        }
        //Check if the year is done
        else if ((peek == ' ' || peek == '\0' || count == 2) && gotYear == false && gotMonth == true && gotDay == true)
        {
          count = 0;
          gotYear = true;
          year = int.Parse(buffer);
          buffer = null;

          if (year >= 80 && year <= 99)
            year += 1900;
          else if (year >= 0 && year <= 79)
            year += 2000;
        }
      }
    }
    bufferDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
  }
  catch (System.Exception ex)
  {
    bufferDate = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
  }
  return bufferDate;
}
```

Comment: This is what happens when you don't do enough research on available functions and try to do things from scratch...

Comment: Is it me or did you just rewrite a new question for one that has been closed one hour before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086209/convert-a-string-of-four-to-six-digits-to-a-date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You discriminator here is the number of spaces. First get that:

```
string source = "....";    
int spaceCount = source.Count(c => c == ' ');
```

Then create formatstrings for the expected range 0..2 . You can use the strings from the question except that you have to use M for the months:

```
var formats = new string[] { "MMddyy", "MMd yy", "M d yy" };
```

and then you can get your date :

```
DateTime r = DateTime.ParseExact(source, formats[spaceCount], null);
```

Add validations as required.

Answer (score 3):

You should use one of the many `Parse` methods defined on `DateTime`.

These will take the string, an optional format string (describing the format of the datetime string) and an optional culture.

Take a look at [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fw7727c.aspx), [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee1y0t7.aspx), [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wteydsd6.aspx) and [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9s47fcc.aspx), some of which will take a `string[]` of the formats to try.

Additionally, here available string formats - [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) date and time format strings.

Comment: Is there a list of acceptable string formats for `DateTime.Parse`?

Comment: @NexAddo - Yes, there is. Answer amended.

Comment: The problem is that he has many format strings he needs to use.

Comment: @McKay - some the parse methods take a `string[]` of the different formats to try. Which you seem to know about from your answer.

Comment: @Oded The ParseExact methods do, not the Parse methods. (hence my answer that actually does take an array of formats)

Comment: @McKay - My first sentence means the many `Parse` methods, including the `Try` and `Exact` variants.

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, new string[] { "MMddyy", "MMd yy", "M d yy" }, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out result);
```

if you need to you can

```
dateString = dateString.Replace('\0', ' ');
```

before you begin

Comment: That's a much more efficient solution. Thanks!